# USB flash drive recognized as Hard Drive

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, usb

I have a serious problem.
I own SandDisk's Cruzer Glide 16GB model and for some reason when I connect it to windows powered computers it recognizes it as a "Local Drive"/Hard Drive and not as a portable storage device AKA Flash Drive but, when I connect it to Linux based OS it shows up as a Flash Drive.

I've searched the all Internet for answer but I found nothing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Does it work anyway? If it does, I wouldn't be worried.

Comment: How if the drive partitioned/formatted?

Comment: @rsenna It is working, but I want to make it a bootable USB and I can't pick it in softwares like unetbootin